# CTI & Custom Object Integration for Click to Call/Dial

Tags: custom-object, cti

In Ring Central, InsideSales, and more, what field type must a field be in order to enable a click to call link?

Answer (score 2):

The field must be a "PHONE" field.  A Formula text wont work or even a regular text.